# Proving an identity involving the alternating sum of products of binomial coefficients

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, summation

Prove the following identity:
$$
\sum_{k\ =\ 0}^{{\large\ell}}\left(-1\right)^{k}
\binom{j - k}{\ell - 1}\binom{\ell}{k} = 0
$$
for some integers $\ell \geq 1$ and $j\geq \ell$.

Using wolfram alpha I have confirmed that this identity is true. But I am not sure how I can prove it myself. I have tried to split it into even and odd values of $k$, but that did not work. I have tried a proof by induction in combination with the identity $\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n-1}{k}+\binom{n-1}{k-1}$, but that also did not work. I think the proof might require a more sophisticated method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your induction idea should work.  Using the identity you suggested, rewrite your expression as
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^l(-1)^k\binom{j-k}{l-1}\binom{l}{k}&=\sum_{k=0}^{l-1}(-1)^k\binom{j-k}{l-1}\binom{l-1}{k}+\sum_{k=1}^l(-1)^k\binom{j-k}{l-1}\binom{l-1}{k-1}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{l-1}(-1)^k\binom{j-k}{l-1}\binom{l-1}{k}-\sum_{k=0}^{l-1}(-1)^k\binom{j-1-k}{l-1}\binom{l-1}{k}.
\end{align}
$$
Now use your identity a second time, applying it to the binomial coefficient $\binom{j-k}{l-1}$ in the first sum.  After cancelling some terms, you will be able to apply induction on $l$.

Comment: Ok, working through as you say: The induction hypothesis is 
$$\sum_{k=0}^{l-1}(-1)^k\binom{j-k}{l-2}\binom{l-1}{k}=0~.$$
After applying the identity for the second time, as you directed, we have
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{l}(-1)^k\binom{j-k}{l-1}\binom{l}{k}&=\sum_{k=0}^{l-1}(-1)^k
\binom{j-k-1}{l-2}\binom{l-1}{k}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{l-1}(-1)^k\binom{j-k}{l-2}\binom{l-1}{k}\frac{j-k-l+2}{j-k}\\
&=-(l-2)\sum_{k=0}^{l-1}(-1)^k\binom{j-k}{l-2}\binom{l-1}{k}\frac{1}{j-k}~.
\end{align}
In the last line I have used the induction hypothesis. But I don't see where to go from here.

Comment: The induction hypothesis is that the statement holds for all $j\ge l-1$.  So you can apply it in your first line.

Comment: Ahhh, that's the piece of information that I've been missing. Much appreciated!

Comment: @Will Orrick I'm sure I'm missing something here, but if the statement is true for $j \geq l-1$, then isn't it automatically true for $j \geq l$ since $l$ is greater than $l-1$? I know this is a couple of years later, but any help you can give would be appreciated.

Comment: @flevinBombastus This identity has two parameters, $l$ and $j$, and we want to prove that it holds for all $l\ge1$ and all $j\ge l$. The induction hypothesis is that it holds for $l=L-1$ for all $j\ge L-1$. This hypothesis immediately implies it holds for all $j\ge L$ when $l=L-1$, but we must still prove the it holds for all $j\ge L$ when $l=L$.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a combinatorial proof. Consider this question:

> How many subsets of the $\{1,2,\dots,j\}$ of size $l-1$ contain all of the numbers $\{1,2,\dots,l\}$?

Obviously, the answer is zero, because there are more than $l-1$ numbers in $\{1,2,\dots,l\}$!

On the other hand, we can count this using the principle of inclusion exclusion. Take all $\binom{j}{l-1}$ subsets of size $l-1$, then for each element $h$ of $\{1,2,\dots,l\}$, subtract $\binom{j-1}{l-1}$ subsets which are missing $h$. Then add back in the doubly subtracted subsets, subtract the triply subtracted subsets, etc. The result is exactly your binomial sum.

Answer (score 0):

We may write

$$\sum_{k=0}^\ell {\ell\choose k} (-1)^k {j-k\choose \ell-1}
= \sum_{k=0}^\ell {\ell\choose k} (-1)^k
[z^{\ell-1}] (1+z)^{j-k}
\\ = [z^{\ell-1}] (1+z)^j
\sum_{k=0}^\ell {\ell\choose k} (-1)^k  (1+z)^{-k}
= [z^{\ell-1}] (1+z)^j  
\left(1-\frac{1}{1+z}\right)^\ell
\\ = [z^{\ell-1}] (1+z)^{j-\ell} z^\ell.$$

We have in any case that  $z^\ell (1+z)^{j-\ell} = z^\ell + \cdots$ so
this term  starts one  power beyond the  coefficient extractor  and is
indeed equal to zero.